# Прохожу самоучитель по JS. Помогите с заданием ---> "Написать функцию, которая выводит свойство innerHTML всех элементов страницы в отдельном окне"

Tags: javascript

"Написать функцию, которая выводит свойство innerHTML всех элементов страницы в отдельном окне".
Написать функцию которая заменяет свойство value у всех текстовых полей на странице.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Получение всех innerHTML на странице.

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName ('*'),
    all = [];

for (var i = 0; els[i]; i++) {
    if (els[i].previousSibling && els[i].previousSibling.nodeType!== 1 ) {
        all.push (els[i].previousSibling);
    };

    all.push (els[i]);

    if (els[i].firstChild && 
        els[i].firstChild.nodeType !== 1 
        && els[i].childNodes.length === 1) {
        all.push (els[i].firstChild);
    };
};
```

## Изменение value всех input на странице.

```
for (var i = 0; i<document.getElementsByTagName ("input").length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByTagName ("input")[i].value = "value";
};
```

Comment: для перебора лучше использовать не for цикл, а функцию forEach()

Comment: @АлександрПиткевич, чем лучше? учитывая, что в коллекции возвращаемой функцией _getElementsByTagName_ нет этого метода